# Replacing Duplicates in a column of list type in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, eda

Background Info: I have a dataframe `df` which has various columns out of which the focus is the column called 'genres'

Goal:

[The problem can be seen in this image, there are entries where duplicates are found for example '[Drama, Romance]' and '[Romance, Drama]' are the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6fJz.png)

1. Now the objective is to remove/replace duplicates programmatically such that the variation is replaced with its equivalent form such as this.

Example:

'[Drama, Romance]' and '[Romance, Drama]'

Now [Romance, Drama] is replaced  with [Drama, Romance] or vice versa instead of complete removal we just replace the list's content

[Output - Before Replacing Duplicates '[Drama, Romance]' and '[Romance, Drama]'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbUdA.png)

[Expected Output - After Replacing Duplicates '[Drama, Romance]'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2jII.png)

2. Filter `df` column 'genres' to only include genres with list entries not exceeding 3 genres for example remove any rows with more than 3 genres. Example of acceptable result in 'genres' column:

- [Romance, Drama, Comedy]
- [Romance, Drama]
- [Drama]

---

I have tried the following:

```
#to delist the 'genres' column
df['genres'] = df.genres.apply(', '.join)

# code sample of manually replaced duplicated content in genres column
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.replace("Romance, Drama","Drama, Romance")
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.replace("Drama, Comedy","Comedy, Drama")
```

The above code works but it is done manually for individual duplicates so I want to find a way to code this for all of the duplicates found in 'genres' column of `df`

Comment: sort the list in the dataframe,and join with a string, then compare the diffenece . `df['genres'].map(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(x)))`

Comment: @codemunchkin in future please don't post images. Please see how to create a minimum reproducible example here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Also, there will probably be another answer or two, so kindly accept when someone has solved for you. Please see here on how to accept a solution: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `list` data type for each row within the column:

1. You can first sort the list per row with `sorted`
2. Then filter the rows of the dataframe with `loc` and get the `value_counts()`

   ```
   df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
   df.loc[df['genres'].apply(lambda x: len(x) <= 3), 'genres'].value_counts()
   ```

Comment: The first line of code works! But the second one gives an error reading " 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts' "